# To show non-existence of Riemann integrable function whose positive Fourier coefficients are $1/n$ and non-positive Fourier coefficients are zero

Tags: fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-series, riemann-integration

How to show that there exist no complex valued Riemann integrable function $f$ on $[-\pi , \pi]$ such that $\hat f (n)=1/n , \forall n \ge 1$ , $\hat f (n)=0 , \forall n \le 0$ ,  where $\hat f (n):=\dfrac 1{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)e^{-int} , \forall n \in \mathbb Z$ ?

If such a Riemann integrable function exist then since $f \in L^1[-\pi , \pi]$ , I can conclude from Uniqueness of Fourier series that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{inx}/n $ a.e. on $[-\pi, \pi]$ . If this equality would hold everywhere then calculating its Abel sum at $x=0$ , I could get a contradiction , but unfortunately the equality holds only a.e. How should I proceed ? Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Presumably you know that there's an $L^2$-function with these Fourier coefficients. Can you identify it? That shows there's no bounded representative, hence no Riemann-integrable representative.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Yes the $L^2$ function is the series that I wrote ... but how do we show there is no bounded representative ?

Comment: If you know which function it is, that is easy to see. Have you an idea what the function is [not its Fourier series, a closed form]?

Comment: @DanielFischer : Unfortunately I don't know any closed form ... I can at best express it as an integral ...

Comment: When you look at the Abel sum, does the series look somehow familiar?

Comment: @DanielFischer : Only the abel sum at $x=0$ looks familiar , which is $A_r(0):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n (e^{in.0}/n)=-log(1-r) $ for $0\le r <1$

Comment: And if for $x\neq 0$ you let $z = r\cdot e^{ix}$, can you see something then?

Comment: @DanielFischer : yes , that is $-log(1-z)$ if $|r|<1$

Comment: Righty-ho. And what happens when we let $r\to 1$?

Comment: @DanielFischer : well $-log(1-z)$ blows up as $r \to 1$ ...

Comment: Not when $z$ approaches a point other than $1$ on the unit circle.

Comment: @DanielFischer :  it approches the Fourier series I wrote in $L^2$ ...

Comment: Right. And the pointwise limit on $[-\pi,0) \cup (0,\pi]$ is what?